# Is a policy of asking questions covering material not covered by lectures common in universities?

Tags: teaching, university, exams, policy

I have come to know a prominent EU university in which it is an official policy that examination questions will be external to the lectures.

For example, say, they are teaching Probability & statistics. Say, they didn't lecture on Poisson distribution. They will put a question on Poisson distribution. If there are 5 questions to answer, they will somehow keep the questions within the syllabus but external to the lecture slides and/or handouts.

I felt that very strange.

Is this policy very common among universities?

Comment: Maybe the purpose is having challenging exercises for the students? Something they can solve, but that they haven't seen before in lectures?

Comment: Need to edit your question to make it more specific.  At my university, the syllabus (or subject outline) is a contract between students and the lecturer.  If it says the subject will teach X, then X must appear.  Otherwise, students have grounds to complain to upper management, especially when they didn't do well in the subject.

Comment: How about a more descriptive title?

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus Are you at a prominent EU university?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, or to make them cover the entire syllabus through self study where needed. It is an interesting idea, actually, if you want to produce scholars.

Comment: @user151413 why does it matter?  I went in to buy an iPhone, and you gave me a Samsung.

Comment: If there is assigned reading, then you are supposed to know it, even if the professor did not re-read it to you in a lecture.

Comment: The question, literally, is about "how common" this is, but I see no discussion of that in comments or the answer. So far, discussion has been about whether this is "appropriate" or not. Personally, I'll guess (but don't know) that it is uncommon except for trivial things, but appropriate provided students are warned _explicitly_ in advance. Perhaps you can edit this a bit to clarify whether it is just frequency you care about (though I think that isn't really answerable).

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus Because this "contractual nature" is very likely very country/region specific.  So my real question was whether you are in the US, Europe (where), or somewhere else; the prominent part was just ironic as it was written like that in the question.  I don't think the syllabus is seen as a contract in many places in Europe.  (I am also a bit critical towards it, since you want to have some flexibility, depending on the pace in which a specific class is going, the interests of the students, etc., so you might want to ne able to adapt to this.)

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus Note that in many countries in Europe, you don't pay for the education. So it is really: "I went in to get a free iPhone, and I got a free Samsung."

Comment: @user151413, is that actually true that "you don't pay..." many places? I'd assumed that had disappeared in the last decade and that there were substantial fees pretty much everywhere. Citation?

Comment: Tutions fees in major EU countries... France (170 Euro), Germany (free), Italy (income based means test), Belgium (375-850 euro), Austria (free), Czech(free in czech lanuage, free in English), Denmark (free), Finland (free), Greece (free), Hungary (free), Iceland (free), Ireland (free for first attempt),

Comment: @Buffy See Ian Sudbery's comment.

Comment: @IanSudbery That's per semester, I assume, with typically 2 semesters per year?

Comment: The real purpose of (most) "how common is X?" question here is to find out "how acceptable X is" is and "can I complain about X?". Or it's a thinly veiled rant and not an actual question...

Comment: @user151413 some are per year, some per semester. See here: https://www.studyineurope.eu/tuition-fees

Comment: @user151413 I'm sure Europe would have law against 'misleading claims'.  Giving a Samsung phone instead of the advertised iPhone surely is against the law.  No?

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus Phones are not syllabi.  Syllabi might say "possible topics include". Syllabi might not even exist, and the lecture is defined by its title.  And there are places beyond the US, and they might work differently, even though it is hard to believe. And laws which apply to phones might not apply to university courses.

Answer (score 9):

If its on the syllabus, then you will be expected to know it. But its not necessary that all material on the syllabus will be taught by lecture.

It might be that the material is part of the prerequisites for the module. It might be part of the recommended reading for the module.

It might be that the question can be solved via application of knowledge taught in the lectures, but this is application of the knowledge to a different situation. For example: I might teach the concepts behind a hypothesis test, and give examples using t-tests. I  might then set questions using the Poisson distribution. As long as I have the appropriate formulas or probability tables, I'd except students to be able to transfer the concept of a hypothesis test from the t distribution to the Poisson distribution.

I would also be aware that this was a difficult question, and would be to separate the top students from the good students, but it would demonstrate that someone had understood the concepts rather than just learning to plug numbers into formulae.

Comment: +1, "the question can be solved via application of knowledge taught in the lectures, but this is application of the knowledge to a different situation" this is the definition of higher levels of questions (problem solving and above) in Bloom's hierarchy. Questions that can be answered by directly repeating lecture material are not problem-solving questions, no matter how difficult. I have seen formal education policies that refer to these levels, so it's most likely that is what the OP's case refers to.

Comment: On the other hand, there are definitely universities where this sort of thing is outright forbidden - if it's on the exam, it has to have been taught in either the lectures or the tutorials.

Comment: @nick012000 so if writing (or reading, or adding) is not taught in lectures or tutorials students can’t write their exams?  That would be very convenient.

Comment: An extreme example is the Cambridge English Tripos, where, at least 15 years ago, students only had one lecture a week.

Comment: @IanSudbery Fifteen years ago?  Wouldn't that be around the time of the famous BeeGees' _Tragedy_ exam question on the Cambridge English Tripos?

Comment: More like 20 years ago now actaully.... I don't know, I didn't do English, I just had friends that did.

Comment: I checked, and the [BeeGees' _Tragedy_ question](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/amp.theguardian.com/education/2001/jul/10/artsandhumanities.highereducation) was in 2001.

Comment: That would have been during my time then, but I was just a boring scientist.

Answer (score 2):

I personally stay away in exams from material not covered in assignments or tutorials, simply out of fairness rather than by a policy requirement.  Once can always argue that, if it’s in the course description or the syllabus, it’s also fair game even if not covered in class but to me at least that’s over the line.

There has to be some flexibility to allow instructors to go beyond what was strictly in the lectures: in an absurd example one could argue that, if the instructor showed in class how to multiply 3x5 but not 4x7, then the first example would be legitimate a legitimate exam question but not the second.

A reasonable boundary is to expect that *topics* covered in class - rather than specific material covered in class - are fair topics.  In the example of my previous paragraph, both are examples of multiplication so both would be fair questions in my mind.

Thus, it is possible to have an exam question on the Poisson distribution if the question deals with properties common to distributions rather than a unique property of the Poisson distribution, provided that distributions were a topic covered in class or tutorials.

I do not know examples where allowing exams questions not covered in class is a *policy*.  I know of plenty of instructors (including myself) who make it a habit of not asking in exams the same examples covered in class, although the exam questions are on *topics* covered in class.